# How can my input to a variable not be defined within python

Tags: python, variables

Im making a program that will ask the user for their first name and surname. 
This data is then saved to a .txt file. 
I understand that the coding is basic and easy to understand but just recently this code has decided to not work.

```
file1 = open("document.txt",'w')

firstname = input("What is your first name?")

secondname = input("what is you second name?")
file1 = open ('document.txt','w')
file1.write (firstname + secondname)

newfile.close()
```

[I am given the following error when running this piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HvXp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `raw_input` in order to get a string in Python 2. `input` is evaluating the user input, seeing the variable `name` which is not defined.